# csc.exe compilation time degradation when "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" package is used

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, roslyn, csc

Our team is currently migrating from C# 5.0 to C# 6.0 syntax so Roslyn compiler should be used instead of the legacy one.

We have to use "csc.exe" as a part of the complex solution compilation process. Build commands look like this:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -nologo -target:library  -out:c:\repo\bin64\deb\common.dll @.\rspE0FF.tmp
```

This command execution takes **~400ms**

"rspE0FF.tmp" content looks like this (it contains much more *.cs files, however, it does not matter, this is reproducible on any set of files):

```
"c:\repo\shared\common\estimation\complexjob.cs"
"c:\repo\shared\common\stringdecorator.cs"
"c:\repo\shared\common\tplextensions.cs"
"/reference:mscorlib.dll" "/reference:System.dll" "/reference:System.Data.dll" "/reference:System.Xml.dll" "/reference:System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" "/reference:System.IdentityModel.dll" "/reference:System.Data.Entity.dll"
```

When Roslyn compiler is used execution time shouts to **~4100ms** 
Command is the same just csc.exe is called from the package folder:

```
c:\NewRepo\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\tools\RoslynLatest\csc.exe -nologo -target:library -out:c:\repo\bin64\deb\common.dll @.\rspE0FF.tmp
```

**We have to build the solution by sequentially running hundreds of csc.exe commands like this. Total compilation time has grown from 2 minutes to 8 minutes.**

Is this performance degradation expected?

Any advice on how to tweak this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roslyn team does not consider someone invoking csc.exe as part of its perf investigations.  Today you are jitting all of csc.exe on each invocation (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12360) for more info).

**Possible solutions:**

- run ngen on the version of csc you are using so hopefully you only
  need to JIT once
- use the compiler server, which in addition to re-using csc instances also caches metadata across builds.

NOTE: the msbuild task does this automatically for you, but in your case you will need to do this manually.

You would need to setup the server (duplicate what [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/f60facc9f40ddc40f85411372f5b8dde9dd5e3b4/src/Compilers/Shared/BuildServerConnection.cs) code is doing) and pass `/server` to all of your csc calls

Comment: ngen of the csc.exe helped greatly. Solution compilation time went down to 3 minutes which is acceptable. here is ngen command: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install /nologo c:\NewRepo\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\tools\RoslynLatest\csc.exe

Comment: However on some environments ngen does not help and csc.exe is being JITted on every call. Unfortunately I was not able to find out what the perequisites for succesfull ngen.

Comment: NGEN images are only valid
1. On the machine they are ngen'd on
2. With the exact version of the .NET Framework they were ngen'd against

If you have updated your framework it would invalidate ngening